# How can i use designs created in Adobe XD in my Angular JS website?

Tags: html, node.js, angularjs, adobe-xd

I have created a design prototype in Adobe XD.
I want to use this prototype design in my web application created in Angular JS

How can i use designs created in Adobe XD in my Angular JS website ?

I searched net and i was able to find a XD plugin to export to HTML and JSS files.

Please let me know.

Comment: That's not what Adobe XD is for. Adobe XD is a software to design a mockup which is then to be implemented by the techology of your desire.

Comment: Yes got it. What i m trying to ask is whether we need to create the design from scratch or can reuse some of the code from html and css

Answer (score 0):

Adobe XD is a prototyping tool only. You need to use something like Dreamweaver to export a design into HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 0):

After you finish your website design in adobexd you can use Desech Studio to import the adobexd file. Then you can install the Angular plugin and integrate with your angular code.

Have a look at the github repo https://github.com/desech/studio-angular to see more details.